# Can we combine users in Piranha CMS on existing MVC 5 site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, piranha-cms

I am very new to CMS - I am trying to learn as I go, and I really like the Piranha concept and layout.

Excuse my question, for it may be noobish - but if I have an existing MVC 5 site based on OWIN / ASP .NET IDentity, with users, roles, etc. Can I combine these users (and roles) with Piranha?

I know Piranha includes OWIN (if I am not mistaken). Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piranha CMS does **NOT** include OWIN, the current version uses Forms Authentication. It has been planned to integrate Piranha CMS with other authentication providers but it hasn't been implemented yet.

Regards

Håkan